# Position icon at the top right corner of a fieldset with legend

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble making the below layout look the same across all browsers:

```css
.wrapper {
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  top: -20px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="wrapper">
  <legend>Legendary!</legend>
  <div class="icon">icon</div>
</fieldset>
```

The problem is that when the `legend` element is present, the `div.icon` is pulled few pixels down on firefox, and a few pixels up on chrome. When I remove the `legend` element, it's working fine, but I can't do that. Any ideas on how to make it look the same everywhere?

Comment: Not sure if its the source of the issue but your html markup is invalid. You are trying to close your fieldset with a div tag.

Comment: That's not the source of the issue :). It's just my typo. It's not present in the original code, but for clearness, I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you have a working UPDATED :[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dpUM2/29/) tested in chrome and firefox.
You don't need to work with `position:absolute;` you can just `float:right;` your div and give `margin-top:-40px;` or whatever value you want.

```
 #wrapper{
         margin-top: 100px;
         position: relative;
         height: 400px;
         width: 400px;
         border: 1px solid black; 
    }

#icon{
 float:right;   
    background-color:#fff;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin-top:-20px;
    margin-right:20px
}
legend#title {
    margin-left: 20px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    background: #f3f5f6;
    width: 74px;
}
```

Comment: Having solved the problem, could you explain *why* this solved the problem? That way we can all learn something useful from your answer that might be applicable to other problems in future.

Comment: I think I can try to explain it :). The `legend` element was interfering with `fieldset` height. Since @edisoni gave it a `float: left` it stopped doing that therefore the legend element was getting a correct height despite some browsers quirks and I could have positioned both problematic elements as I wanted :).

Comment: I guess this wont be responsive which you mentioned in your question you need to have.

Comment: @sumitbadaya how could it be responsive when he has everything in fixed value in pixels ?

Comment: That's what I said. He mentioned about "look the element same everywhere". That should include responsiveness too, but he accepted this answer so was wondering how could this be an accepted answer if it fails responsiveness !!!

Comment: He said that meaning that he wanted the view to look the same across all browsers because this was his problem, he didn't said that it displays different in mobile and in desktop.

Comment: Don't know if any of you tested it by viewing in a 'mobile' view or not, but it is responsive enough, meaning that both elements stay in the same place and preserve the same margins (I don't want THESE margins to change anyhow on mobile devices).

Answer (score 0):

```
 .icon {
           float: right;
           margin-top: -30px;
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            background-color: white;


        }
```

tested on chrome as well as mozilla.

Comment: But the problem is rendering it under chrome and firefox. Don't care about edge :)

Comment: tried coming up with something new.
apologize if it is still wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Try giving `top` value in percentage `%`.

```
.icon {
                position: absolute;
                width: 40;
                height: 40px;
                border: 1px solid black;
                background-color: white;
                top: -2.5%;
                right: 10px;
            }
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/37y8023g/

Comment: Changing top from px to percent didn't change anything.

Answer (score -1):

Use `line-height` for `.icon`

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    margin-top: 100px;
    position: relative;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}            
.icon {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    top: -20px;
    right: 10px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/qjqv43y4/1/

Comment: This also didn't change anything. Just run it under FF and Chrome - you'll see.